# How to keep track of the id number in an object when you iterate and add another object to it

Tags: javascript

I want to add another object to my exiting object but i doesn't get the value as others object have instead it gets a text, I tried a easy solution but didn't work, here is that i'm facing:

[ConsoleLog Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hGJh.png)

So instead of the key long I want to keep the numbers as they started from 0, but I don't know how?

Here is what I've tried:

```js
  const addToWatchlist = (movie) => {
    const long = movies.length;
    const data = {...movies, long: movie};
    setMovies(movies)
```

ps: I'm using React.

Comment: `const data = {...movies, [long]: movie}`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const addToWatchlist = (movie) => {
movies.push(movie)
setMovies(movies)
```